# BASH: Assign special symbol to a variable

Tags: bash

As a system Administrator I have to work on different servers with different keyboard layouts. So every time I face huge problem with finding keys like '&' ,'|'.

Is there any way I can assign these symbols to a variable and call the variable when ever I need a symbol ?

For example: Assume

```
echo "|" > filename
pipe = $(cat filename)

ps -ef somethinghere($(pipe)) grep java
```

should give me running java process.  I tried everything I could but failed.

Please help.

Comment: Isn't it easier to change the keyboard layout ?

Comment: @Derlin no. Other users from same locale might be using with same user creds.

Comment: This doesn't work because **data** is not parsed as **syntax** -- if it were, handling hostile data (say, a file named `/tmp/$(rm -rf $HOME)`) would be almost impossible.

Comment: ...which is to say, letting a variable stand in for a syntactic element would be breaking innate security protections. If you're a sysadmin, and running with more privileges than the people using the systems you're on day-to-day, then circumventing measures intended to prevent that data from running code under your (privileged) account is the **last** thing you should do.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I can take care of these issues.

Comment: You can? You never write `for file in *.txt` without reviewing each and every filename that glob will expand to manually? Because I've been a sysadmin for plenty of years and **I** certainly run scripts that execute over data I haven't manually reviewed. (Indeed, if you're looping over tens of thousands of names, you **can't** manually review them).

Comment: The worst data loss events I've seen were caused by people who made assumptions -- "names in directory X can only ever be [0-9a-f], so their expansions don't need to be quoted", for instance. Until a program writing to that directory had a buffer overflow and dumped random garbage from memory into a filename, and that garbage contained a whitespace-surrounded `*`; scripts tried to delete that one file, and deleted the entire directory -- full of billing-data backups.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , All my purpose is running a ps -ef | grep java command

Comment: If that's truly your purpose, you should just use `pgrep java` instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , oh come on . thats an example. I dont write complex regex, big scripts with this logic

Comment: What you *do*, on a day-to-day habitual sense, becomes your habit. Those habits are what you leverage going forward in the future, as you move on to bigger and more important things. I'm completely serious here in a speaking-from-experience way that building your habits out of best-practice components is serious business, and an essential component at being good at what you do.

Answer (score 3):

The following function will do the job:

```
# read a number of arguments on the left-hand side; those actual arguments; then the RHS
pipe() {
  local nargs
  local -a firstCmd

  nargs=$1; shift
  firstCmd=( )
  for ((i=0; i<nargs; i++)); do
    firstCmd+=( "$1" ); shift
  done
  "${firstCmd[@]}" | "$@"
}

# basic use case
pipe 3 ps -ef somethinghere grep java

# or, for a pipeline with more than two components:
pipe 3 ps -ef somethinghere pipe 2 grep java tee log.txt
```

What's better is that **unlike** a solution using `eval`, it'll work even with more complicated values:

```
pipe 3 ps -ef 'something with spaces here' grep java
```

One could also write a version of this function that uses a sigil value:

```
pipe() {
  local sigil
  local -a firstCmd

  sigil=$1; shift
  firstCmd=( )
  while (( $# )); do
    if [[ $1 = "$sigil" ]]; then
      shift
      "${firstCmd[@]}" | pipe "$sigil" "$@"
      return
    else
      firstCmd+=( "$1" )
      shift
    fi
  done
  "${firstCmd[@]}"
}
```

In this case, you could even do:

```
sigil=$(uuidgen) # generate a random, per-session value
pipe "$sigil" ps -ef 'something with spaces here' "$sigil" grep java "$sigil" tee log.txt
```

Comment: Do you see issues with implementing the solution as a onliner like `pipe() { "${@:2:$1}" | "${@:$(($1+2))}" ; }`?  I think this would be equivalent to your first proposed solution.  A little cryptic maybe...

Comment: Plausible, but I'd rather verbose and readable code. If you want to provide a condensed version as a separate answer, feel free.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do that, here is a way:

```
pipe="|"
eval $(echo ps -ef $pipe grep java)
```

with cat:

```
eval $(echo ps -ef $(cat pipe.txt) grep java)
```

Note that using `eval` is discouraged and that this command will become problematic as soon as you need complex commands involving quotes, escape sequences, filenames and/or arguments with spaces, etc.

In my opinion, it would be better for you to familiarise yourself with how to change keyboard layouts on different linux systems (see  `loadkeys` for example).

Comment: This works in very limited circumstances. Start dealing with filenames with spaces; commands that require quoting; etc. and it'll break down quickly.

Comment: ...as a slightly less problematic variant, `eval "ps -ef $pipe grep java"` is at least *explicit* about what it's doing (generating a single string that's evaluated as code), making the associated side effects a little more obvious to the reader (thus, the need to use literal rather than syntactic quotes, ie. `eval "ps -ef $pipe grep \"java -Xmx\""` or such when adding more words).

Answer (score 1):

Building on the same logic as the first solution proposed by CharlesDuffy, this should be equivalent :

```
pipe()
{
    "${@:2:$1}" | "${@:$(($1+2))}"
}
```

Rather than using iteration to build an array with the first command and shift arguments until the remaining ones contain only the second command, this solution uses expansions.

- `"${@:2:$1}"` expands `$1` arguments, starting at position 2
- `"${@:$(($1+2))}"` expands all arguments starting at position `$1` + 2.

In both cases, the double quotes ensure arguments expand as one word per argument (no word splitting being performed).

If you find this too cryptic, feel free to avoid it, as readability (to the intended coder(s) who would some day have to maintain the code) is likely to trump any advantage.